# Implementing TabLayout with fragments in another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I am having the problem, as mentioned in the title. When I implement the tabs they don't display the content, and the tab is not smooth, exactly like in this problem:

[TabLayout with viewpager not smooth scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252391/tablayout-with-viewpager-not-smooth-scrolling)

So they can stop in between and so on.

What do you think am I doing wrong? I attach the code of the fragment displaying it:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.news_feed)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.bio)));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        mPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);
        return view;
    }
```

And the layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context="com.my.app.profileFragment">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_below="@id/main_profile_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
        <!--android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"-->
        <!--android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"-->

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</FrameLayout>
```

What is wrong here? I really can't spot an error.

Thank you in advance!

Yours,

Grzegorz

Comment: [Answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058819/android-tablayout-inside-fragment), Please have a look. And this question is duplicate

Comment: I am not seeing the connection. I create two, separate fragments in the pager. How is that connected?

Comment: Is this ViewPager inside a fragment?

Comment: @AswinPAshok - yes, that is when the problem occurs. Before that I displayed it from Activity and it worked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22677595/7557205
Try this.. Something like this happened to me and this worked.
`getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: It works! Thank you! Please add it as a response, so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have a fragment which behaves as a container of fragments, you must use the `getChildFragmentManager()` method of the fragment. If you use the `getSupportFragmentManager()` you will basically use the fragment manager which behaves the way the activity lifecycle goes, not the way your fragment does. ([Reference](http://nmp90.com/2015/07/getsupportfragmentmanager-vs-getchildfragmentmanager/))

So instead of using `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`, use `getChildFragmentManager()`